# SORT BY CASE IF statement

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, case

Here is what I have tried. I get zero results when there should be many. Any help would be appreciated!

This is the Order By code:

```
ORDER BY category ASC,
  CASE WHEN Business_Zip IN 'Certified_Zips' THEN Search_Order WHEN Business_Zip NOT IN 
'Certified_Zips' THEN Search_Order_2 END ASC,
  Referrals DESC,Business_Name,Login,id ASC";
```

and this is the entire query:

```
"SELECT * FROM DATA" WHERE Zip_Radius LIKE '%$zipradius%' AND category NOT 
LIKE '$category' AND category NOT LIKE '$category2' AND category NOT LIKE 
'$category3' 

AND category2 NOT LIKE '$category' AND category2 NOT LIKE ('$category2' AND 
category2 != '') AND category2 NOT LIKE ('$category3' AND category3 != '')


AND category3 NOT LIKE '$category' AND category3 NOT LIKE ('$category2' AND 
category2 != '') AND category3 NOT LIKE ('$category3' AND category3 != '')

ORDER BY category ASC,

CASE WHEN Business_Zip IN 'Cerified_Zips' THEN Search_Order ELSE Business_Zip 
NOT IN 'Certified_Zips' 
THEN Search_Order_2 END ASC,

Referrals DESC,Business_Name,Login,id ASC";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "stuff....";
}
} else {
echo "no results";
}}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: *I get zero results when there should be many.* ORDER BY cannot influence on the returned rows amount.

Comment: You are probably getting a syntax error. Look up how to handle SQL errors in PHP. This: `Business_Zip IN 'Cerified_Zips'` is invalid. After `IN` there is supposed to come a set of values, e.g. `Business_Zip IN (1234, 5678)`, not a string like `'Cerified_Zips'`. The rest of your `CASE` expression is also invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Your "Order by code" doesn't match the "entire query" code. Do you have a second "WHEN" or an "ELSE"? If you have an ELSE, I don't think it can be followed by a "NOT IN"/"THEN". If you have a second WHEN, I'd suggest replacing it with a "ELSE Search_Order_2 END".

EDIT: Incorporating @Akina's comment, I agree that the Order By cannot influence the number of rows returned. So, you might have an error in your code. Suggestion to replace second WHEN with ELSE stands.

EDIT2: Seeing more of the code, I'd try modifying it the following way:

```
"SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE Zip_Radius LIKE '%$zipradius%' AND category NOT 
LIKE '$category' AND category NOT LIKE '$category2' AND category NOT LIKE 
'$category3' 

AND category2 NOT LIKE '$category' AND category2 NOT LIKE '$category2' AND 
category2 != '' AND category2 NOT LIKE '$category3' AND category3 != ''


AND category3 NOT LIKE '$category' AND category3 NOT LIKE '$category2' AND 
category2 != '' AND category3 NOT LIKE '$category3' AND category3 != ''

ORDER BY category ASC,

CASE WHEN Business_Zip IN 'Cerified_Zips' THEN Search_Order ELSE Search_Order_2 END ASC,

Referrals DESC,Business_Name,Login,id ASC";
```

Comment: My bad... I have corrected the "entire query" part

Comment: Tried as suggested: CASE WHEN Business_Zip IN 'Cerified_Zips' THEN Search_Order ELSE Business_Zip 
NOT IN 'Certified_Zips' 
THEN Search_Order_2 END ASC, (Same result)

Comment: Perhaps my edited answer helps? I removed your ()'s because I don't think ('$category2' AND category2 != '') gives you what you want. And I modified the ELSE.

Answer (score 0):

First I want to thank everyone for their help! It is much appreciated.

This ended working for me and my situation. Hope it helps others in the future:

```
    SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE Zip_Radius LIKE '%$zipradius%' AND category NOT LIKE '$category' AND category NOT LIKE '$category2' AND category NOT LIKE '$category3' 

AND category2 NOT LIKE '$category' AND category2 NOT LIKE ('$category2' AND category2 != '') AND category2 NOT LIKE ('$category3' AND category3 != '')


AND category3 NOT LIKE '$category' AND category3 NOT LIKE ('$category2' AND category2 != '') AND category3 NOT LIKE ('$category3' AND category3 != '')

ORDER BY category ASC,

CASE WHEN Business_Zip LIKE '$Seal_Zips' THEN Search_Order ELSE Search_Order_2 END 
ASC,Referrals DESC,Business_Name,Login,id ASC
```